# Setting background color on Extjs Textfield

Tags: css, extjs, textbox

I am trying to set a background color to a textfield when its value is greater than 75. so I added the below code to the listener

```
listeners: {
       beforeRender: function(e) {
           if (someValue >= 75) {
               e.style = " background-color: #00CC99";
           }
       }
 }
```

but i get something like below when it renders,

[image]

is there a way to make the green color visible in the entire text box instead of just buttom? I figured out that it is not displaying as intended because of the default CSS's background image. But i want to change the css on change of the value and not write seperate css for just one textbox. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just get rid of the background image:

```
e.style = "background-image:none;background-color:#00cc99;";
/* or */
e.style = "background:none #00cc99;";
```

If `e` is a DOM object use [`element.style.property = 'value'`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) instead:

```
e.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
e.style.backgroundColor = '#00cc99';
/* or */
e.style.background = 'none #00cc99';
```

For the sake of completeness the definition in ExtJS (according to the [ExtJS "Form Field Types" demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/field-types.html)):

```
.x-form-field,.x-form-text{
    /* ... */
    background:url("../../resources/themes/images/default/form/text-bg.gif") 
         repeat-x scroll 0pt 0pt white;
}
```

Comment: so i put a listener on the box, when the value change i simply get the reference of the element through the change function and trying to set the style property just as you described but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other method i could use to set the new style values?

Comment: You could provide a [working online example](http://sscce.org/) of your problem and include it in your question ;). Use http://jsfiddle.net/ for example.

Comment: I got it, i was using e.style to set the values which is not working, so i used firebug to see what actually this element has in it, turns out there is method called setStyle in "el" object of "e". So i changed it to  e.el.setStyle("background-image", "none");                                                    e.el.setStyle("background-color", "#00cc99"); which works perfectly. thanks